# Node red JSON object

Tags: json, telegram-bot, node-red

I have object message in node red like this :

`{ chatId: 111111111, messageId: 1111, type: "message", content: "VENT Auto", date: "2017-12-28T19:46:45.000Z",inbound: true }`

I want to parse this message and write if function like this :

```
if (chatId==111111111){return msg;}
```

I tried these :
[json parse-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983841/how-can-i-parse-out-json-in-a-node-red-function?rq=1)

[json-parse-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38829829/json-node-red-extract)

[json-parse-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026642/node-red-json-object-how-to-extract-json-values)

this is the function in node red :

```
msg=msg.payload.chatId
return msg
```

I want to see the chatid in the output :

```
if (msg.payload.chatid== 11111111){return msg)
```

and msg is the output of this funtion :

```
[{"id":"b068944.8218168","type":"chatbot-telegram-receive","z":"52d0aba5.3f0a3c","bot":"","x":170,"y":600,"wires":[["f479d424.fe9e3"]]},{"id":"f479d424.fe9e3","type":"function","z":"52d0aba5.3f0a3c","name":"","func":"\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":370,"y":620,"wires":[["c8f111dc.9ac8d"]]},{"id":"ba82cead.cdf808","type":"change","z":"52d0aba5.3f0a3c","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"payload.content","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":580,"y":620,"wires":[["5f96e508.3d69cc"]]},{"id":"c8f111dc.9ac8d","type":"function","z":"52d0aba5.3f0a3c","name":"","func":"msg=msg.payload.chatId\nreturn msg\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":330,"y":700,"wires":[["ba82cead.cdf808"]]}]
```

I send message to telegram bot and I want to compare the chatid to my chat id.

Comment: Firstly, Node-RED function nodes use JavaScript not Java. Secondly Stack Overflow doesn't work this way, you have to try for yourself and then somebody will help you fix what you have already tried.

Comment: I tried some ways but I didn't find a question like this.

Comment: Then edit the question to show us what you've tried

Comment: I saw those links before I ask the question.

Comment: No, I said show us what YOU have actually already tried, not what other questions you have read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always return a whole message object from a function node. You are trying to return just a string, this will not work.

If you just want to prevent the passing of a message that does not match the id you can do it one of 2 ways.

1. Use a function node with the following code:

   ```
   if (msg.payload.chatId == "111111111") {
     return msg;
   }
   ```

   This will only allow the message to pass if the `chatId` is `111111111`
2. Use a switch mode with the following:

   [image]